# How to prevent Jenkins to get the entire TFS workspace?

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to build a single project in what is essentially a monorepo.

Using the TFS plugin in Jenkins I set the Project path to the specific project I want to build, and set the local workfolder in advanced settings accordingly. This way I could get all the project dependencies from the monorepo that I need to build this one project using a script inside the Jenkinsfile. At least that is what I thought.

As soon as I mapped the Jenkins workspace to the repository root, Jenkins seems to get the entire repository on build, which eventually fails with an out of memory exception, completely ignoring what I set in "Project path".

But even if it wouldn't fail, it's not really a realistic idea to have a complete copy of the entire repo for every project we want to build.

How can this be solved? Stop using the TFS plugin and do all TFS operations in the Jenkinsfile maybe?

Comment: I hope you are not checking in binary dependencies into tfvc. You should be using an atrifact repo like Artifactory or Nexus. TFVC plugin only allows you to map a single path to the workspace, unlike the sdk cli tool. In a freestyle job, if  you must load from  $/  into the workspace, SCM | Advanced ... section, you can add all the directories you want excluded into the Cloaked Paths section. Not sure about pipeline: we use git for our pipelines. Again, no binaries in git repos.

Comment: Yeah I thought about using cloaked paths, but there are a lot of projects in the repo, so that would be a long list to maintain. I hoped to kind of work around the limitations of the TFS plugin, but it seems I have to do everything manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have `$/Repo/project` and `$/Repo/dependency` . You just need to pull both of those into Jenkins for a single build.  Naturally you tried `$/Repo` root, but this gave you a bunch of other projects along with.

Completely ignoring what I set in "Project path". You may use multiple project path.

The TFS pluging for Jenkins currently does **not support checking out the sources from multiple locations**.

As a solution, just as Ian W pointed out you have ability to **cloak folders** in your $\Repo that you are not interested in. Checkins to cloaked folders will not trigger a build. Unfortunately according to your comment that may be a lot of folders.

Another solution to this is to create several Jobs, some that just download your dependency and another to make the build.

For example, create three jobs in Jenkins, each "downstream" of the other:

> Try to build uses $/Repo/project (as workspace\TheProgram), and
>   $/Repo/dependency (as workspace\Framework).
>
> - Framework-Get: normal source code triggering on TFS' Project Path of `$/Repo/project`.  No build step.
> - TheProgram-Get: normal source code triggering on TFS' Product Path of `$/Repo/dependency`.  No build step.
> - TheProgram-Build: No source code control.  But the build steps xcopy's the source from the above two steps.  Then, you can run a
>     normal build step.
>
> TheProgram-Build's first build step is a windows batch command:
>
> ```
>  REM ==================================== REM First Get the
> Framework folder: rmdir /s/q Framework mkdir Framework xcopy /y /q /e
> ..\..\Framework-Get\Workspace\Framework Framework
>
> REM ==================================== REM Then Get the TheProgram
> Folder: rmdir /s/q TheProgram  mkdir TheProgram  xcopy /y /q /e
> ..\..\TheProgram-Get\Workspace\TheProgram TheProgram
> ```
>
> The second build step was a simple call to build use msbuild or
>   whatever you like here.

You could also combine job1 and job3 together to simplify your workflow, which actually only need two jobs.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question.

Comment: @Name Sorry, my mistake for misunderstanding. Have updated the response. Kindly check it. You should either use multiple jobs or cloaked feature. If you not want to manually add cloaked path. It's also able to achieve the feature by using both TF and the powershell Snapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell. Use `TF Workfold /unmap` command to unmap and remove the default $/ mapping which is made during workspace creation.  Then use TF Workfold /map (To map specific locations, ie $/Repo/project)

Comment: Thanks for the update! I think this is what I am going to do. It feels a little bit hacky, but there does not seem to be a better solution.

Comment: @patricklu-msft, is there any chance someone at MSFT is ever going to get back to working on and releasing an update to the plugin to handle basic things like multi-paths into a workspace? Or the TaskListener failure? No real improvements in nearly 20 months, meanwhile there are idle PRs and [lots of issues](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61420?filter=10230&jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened)%20AND%20component%20%3D%20tfs-plugin) still being assigned to redsolo, who has not worked on that for 5 years!